# Google Sheets: How to restart Arrayformula execution in two separate tabs

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have 2 columns, in 2 separate tabs that I would like to combine in 1 column, in Tab #3. However, To combine them, I have a number of conditions that should be met in order to choose which values in tab#1 or tab#2 to transfer to tab#3

The issue I am facing is, when the conditional formula goes through all the rows in Tab#1 (using Arrayformula), Arrayformula starts executing on the row number from where it stopped at in Tab#1. I want Arrayformula to start executing, in tab#2 starting from row 1

Do you have an idea of how I can restart the Arrayformula row position (when in Tab#2)?

EDIT:
here is the formula I am using
In Tab 3, I added this formula:

=arrayformula(ifs('Tab 1'!A2:A<>"",Tab1'!B2:B, 'Tab 2'!A2:A<>"",'Tab 2'!A2:A))

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your formula and some sample to understand your scenario?

Comment: Hi Martin, sure, here is the formula: =arrayformula(ifs('Tab 1'!A2:A<>"",Tab1'!B2:B, 'Tab 2'!A2:A<>"",'Tab 2'!A2:A))  FYI, I simplified it, as I want to highlight the issue that I am facing, I.e I want to scan Column 1 in Tab 1, then scan Column 1 in Tab 2, but starting from the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to repeat the same process through the columns in both tabs you can use curly brackets. That would repeat the same process over the two tabs, but it's not that clear which is your desired result:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF({Tab1!A2:A;Tab2!A2:A}<
"",{Tab1!B2:B;Tab2!B2:B},""))
```

Comment: this solves it!! thank you do much!! however, the issue I am facing is that multiple blank rows are add from Tab1, before the formula switches to Tab2. I tried ISBLANK and also tried Len(), but I still don't seem to get rid of the blank rows.. any idea?

Comment: You can try with QUERY, maybe simplify your formula too: `=QUERY({Tab1!A2:B;Tab2!A2:B},"SELECT Col2 where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null",)`

Comment: Cool, this works! , though, is there a way to add a condition, something like: in Tab 3, select Col1 from Tab1 and Col1 from Tab2, if the Value of Col1 of Tab1 = Value of Col1 of Tab2

Comment: How would they match? By row number in each sheet? I suggest you try and upload a new question with your attempts and struggles, and we'll be able to help!

Comment: Sure! I added it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677584/adding-multiple-conditions-to-separate-tabs-in-a-sheet-when-using-query