# Adding multiple conditions to separate tabs, in a sheet, when using Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

in Google Sheets, I am trying to combine values found in separate columns, from 2 tabs, into one column, in a third tab (Tab 3). There are a number of conditions that I would like to add so specific values are extracted to Tab3. How do I add conditions when querying in Tab3?

here is an example

Tab1
ID  Value
1   CL1
2   CL2
3   CL3
4   CL4
5   CL5
6   CL6

Tab 2

ID  Value
111 v1
222 v2
3   v3
444 v4
v5
6   v6
777 v7
888 v8
999 v9

in Tab3, I'd like to:
1- Extract all values in Tab2, that are not included in Tab1
2- If there are values in Tab2 that are equal to Tab1, then use the value in Tab2, when added to Tab3
3- If there are values in Tab2 that do not exist in Tab1, then add those values too
4- Disregard any empty cells after the last column value

All 3 conditions should be added into 1 column in Tab 3

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this;

```
=LAMBDA(un,{FILTER(un,un<>""), BYROW(FILTER(un,un<>""),LAMBDA(id,IFNA(VLOOKUP(id,{Tab2!A2:B;Tab1!A2:B},2,0))))})
(UNIQUE({Tab1!A2:A;Tab1!A2:A}))
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! would it be possible to elaborate on LAMBDA, un, and BYROW? I can look them up, though it would be great to understand your reasoning behind this formula

Comment: LAMBDA allows you to name a variable (a range, a result from an operation, etc.) in order to apply a process. With the help of other auxiliary formulas (such as BYROW) you can instruct it to repeat a formula over a certain array. In this case, I grabbed all unique values from Tab1 and Tab2, naming them "un" (for unique). Filtered them because there would probably be one empty value. Then, with curly brackets I stated to list all the unique values `{un,`  ...

Comment: ... and then with BYROW _row by row_ I used VLOOKUP to find the first appearance of each value --> in this case I looked first in the 2nd tab and then in the 1st one -> `{Tab2!A2:B;Tab1!A2:B}`. So if there was a value listed in Tab2 it would be found first _"overwriting"_ the value of Tab1. Hope it's clear enough!